# How to simply render ID3D11Texture2D

Tags: directx-11, direct2d

I am doing a D2D/D3D interoperability program. After getting ID3D11Texture2D from the outside, it is rendered in a designated area. I tried CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget but no effect

- code below, The code runs "normally", there are no errors and debugging information is displayed, But the interface shows a black screen. If you ignore the param texture, changing to only _back_render_target->FillRectange is effective

  ```
   HRESULT CGraphRender::DrawTexture(ID3D11Texture2D* texture, const RECT& dst_rect)
   {
   float dpi = GetDpiFromD2DFactory(_d2d_factory);

   CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D>        temp_texture2d;
   CComPtr<ID2D1RenderTarget>      temp_render_target;
   CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap>            temp_bitmap;

   D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC    desc = { 0 };
   texture->GetDesc(&desc);
   CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC capture_texture_desc(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, desc.Width, desc.Height, 1, 1, D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET);
   HRESULT hr = _d3d_device->CreateTexture2D(&capture_texture_desc, nullptr, &temp_texture2d);
   RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

   CComPtr<IDXGISurface>   dxgi_capture;
   hr = temp_texture2d->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&dxgi_capture));
   RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

   D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES rt_props = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT, D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED), dpi, dpi);
   hr = _d2d_factory->CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget(dxgi_capture, rt_props, &temp_render_target);
   RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

   D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES bmp_prop = D2D1::BitmapProperties(D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED), dpi, dpi);
   hr = temp_render_target->CreateBitmap(D2D1::SizeU(desc.Width, desc.Height), bmp_prop, &temp_bitmap);
   RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

   CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> immediate_context;
   _d3d_device->GetImmediateContext(&immediate_context);
   if (!immediate_context)
   {
       return E_UNEXPECTED;
   }
   immediate_context->CopyResource(temp_texture2d, texture);

   D2D1_POINT_2U src_point = D2D1::Point2U();
   D2D1_RECT_U src_rect = D2D1::RectU(0, 0, desc.Width, desc.Height);
   hr = temp_bitmap->CopyFromRenderTarget(&src_point, temp_render_target, &src_rect);
   RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

   D2D1_RECT_F d2d1_rect = { (float)dst_rect.left, (float)dst_rect.top, (float)dst_rect.right, (float)dst_rect.bottom};
   _back_render_target->DrawBitmap(temp_bitmap, d2d1_rect);

   return S_OK;
   }
  ```
- Refer to [DirectXTK](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Sprites-and-textures), DirectXTK's SpritBatch code has a brief look. It is necessary to introduce a bunch of context settings. I don’t understand the relationship yet. I don’t know. Does the existing code have any influence, such as setting TargetView, ViewPort or even Shader.
- Is there a relatively simple and effective method, as simple and violent as ID2D1RenderTarget's DrawBitmap?

Comment: Aren't you missing the ID2D1RenderTarget::BeginDraw / EndDraw calls?

Comment: Refer to http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut05.html, I wrap a class CTextureDraw, which is implemented internally: 1. Initialize ID3D11ShaderResourceView, two triangles with Vertex/Index Buffer, vs/ps shader and ID3D11SamplerState; 2. Render deviceContext various IAxxx, VSxxx, PSxxx, DrawIndexed